# How to refactor code for deprecated alias_method_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecated

I'm upgrading my rails application and I'm getting a warning saying `alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead`. But I'm not really understanding how to handle this. How can I change the code below?

```
  def read_attribute_with_mapping(attr_name)
    read_attribute_without_mapping(ADDRESS_MAPPING[attr_name] || attr_name)
  end
  alias_method_chain :read_attribute, :mapping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepend` is basically like importing a module, but it ends up "in front" of other code (so the module can call `super` to run the code it's in front of).

This is a runnable example with something close to your situation.

```
module MyModule
  def read_attribute(attr_name)
    super("modified_#{attr_name}")
  end
end

class Example
  prepend MyModule

  def read_attribute(attr_name)
    puts "Reading #{attr_name}"
  end
end

Example.new.read_attribute(:foo)
# Outputs: Reading modified_foo
```

I defined `read_attribute` directly on `Example`, but it could just as well have been a method inherited from a superclass (such as `ActiveRecord::Base`).

This is a shorter but more cryptic version that uses an anonymous module:

```
class Example
  prepend(Module.new do
    def read_attribute(attr_name)
      super("modified_#{attr_name}")
    end
  end)

  def read_attribute(attr_name)
    puts "Reading #{attr_name}"
  end
end

Example.new.read_attribute(:foo)
# Outputs: Reading modified_foo
```

UPDATE:

Just for fun and to address a question below, here's how it could be done without having to explicitly make any modules yourself. I don't think I'd choose to do it this way myself, since it obscures a common pattern.

```
# You'd do this once somewhere, e.g. config/initializers/prepend_block.rb in a Rails app.
class Module
  def prepend_block(&block)
    prepend Module.new.tap { |m| m.module_eval(&block) }
  end
end

# Now you can do:
class Example
  prepend_block do
    def read_attribute(attr_name)
      super("modified_#{attr_name}")
    end
  end

  def read_attribute(attr_name)
    puts "Reading #{attr_name}"
  end
end

Example.new.read_attribute(:foo)
# Outputs: Reading modified_foo
```

Comment: If this is only used in one place can I just add it in that class not as a module?

Comment: No, `prepend` needs a module, but it can be an anonymous, inline module as in my second example above. I added a third example just for fun of how one *could* hide that module, but you most likely don't want to do that. It saves very little typing for little if any win, in my opinion. It's possible to achieve this without modules, like `alias_method_chain` does, but it's usually more pleasant to stick with The Rails Way unless you've got strong reasons not to.